# Not an int attribute - is it a bug?

Tags: postgresql, llvm, postgis

My Postgres (having PostGIS extension) crashed during this execution:

```
SELECT MIN(LENGTH(ST_ASTEXT(way))) FROM planet_osm_polygon;
```

The logging say:

```
error: Not an int attribute (Producer: 'LLVM15.0.6' Reader: 'LLVM 14.0.6')
```

[See the relevant Schema and Data](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/planet/2023/planet-230501.osm.bz2)

Any idea?

Comment: Please show relevant schema and if possible the data causing the error.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to find the smallest length of a way?

Comment: @TimothyDalton Programatically, yes. I like to test an parser for the text-representation.

Comment: Couldn't you use `MIN(ST_Length(way.the_geom::geog))` or something similar?

Comment: @TimothyDalton No because a small object can have a huge text-representation. Also it does not help with the error.

Comment: I see - could you use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NPoints.html instead?

Comment: This seems like it might be a problem with JIT (Just-In-Time compilation, which LLVM is used for).  Try disabling JIT in 'postgresql.conf'.  JIT is not very useful in PostgreSQL and causes a lot of problems, and in my opinion it should be off by default, but sadly it is on by default.